# ConTeXt: Override global project value within a product

Tags: environments, context, document-configuration, directory, organisation

## Background

Looking to understand the definitive relationship between projects, products, environments, and components.

## Minimum Working Example

Here's the directory structure showing the problem:

```
project
├── project/novel
│   ├── project/novel/component.tex
│   ├── project/novel/contents.tex
│   ├── project/novel/prd_para.tex
│   └── project/novel/product.tex
├── project/prj_para.tex
└── project/project.tex
```

### ./project/project.tex

```
\startproject project
  \environment prj_para

  \product product
\stopproject
```

### ./project/prj_para.tex

```
\startenvironment prj_para
  \define\bookname{Project Name}
\stopenvironment
```

### ./project/novel/prd_para.tex

```
% Does not override \bookname from prj_para.tex?
\startenvironment prd_para
  \define\bookname{Product Name}
\stopenvironment
```

### ./project/novel/component.tex

```
\startcomponent component
  \project project

  \bookname

  \input contents
\stopcomponent
```

### ./project/novel/contents.tex

```
Pride and Prejudice

Jane Austen

\section[title={chapter-1},reference={chapter-1}]

It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife.
```

### ./project/novel/product.tex

```
\startproduct
  \project project

  \environment prd_para

  \component component
\stopproduct
```

### Building

The project is built from within the `project` directory:

```
context novel/product --path=novel
```

## Setup

The following setup is what I'd like to achieve:

[image: Project Structure]

Every **product** "inherits" its environment settings from a global **project**. Each **product** can override specific settings. For example, the **project** could define *Arial* as the base font for all products, but one product could redefine it as *Helvetica*.

## Problem

Ideally, the setups in the project-level `prj_para.tex` (i.e., "project-wide" as per the [project structure diagram](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/File:Project-structure.png)) could be changed in the product-level `prd_para.tex`.

However, the value for `\bookname` is always `Project Name`, rather than `Product Name`. Here is how the output appears:

[image: Example Output]

## Question

Using environments, projects, products, and components, how can setups in the project-wide environments be changed by the product-specific environments?

In short, how can "Product Name" be output instead?

## References

Various documentation sources seem to contradict each other, for example [startcomponent](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startcomponent) shows:

```
\startcomponent *
   \project projectname
```

While [Project structure](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure) shows:

```
\startcomponent c_editorial
  \product prd_year2004-01 % but you can use it in other products anyway
```

Neither [Magazine #1101, July 2011](http://pragma-ade.com/general/magazines/mag-1101.pdf) nor [Magazine #1101, September 2016](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/magazines/mag-1101-mkiv.pdf) explicitly state how `\startcomponent`/`\stopcomponent` is codified in relation to either projects or products.

The mailing list has numerous questions with specific answers, but nothing broad in scope. A [Python Script](https://github.com/fiee/tools/blob/master/contextproject.py) generates files and directories, but without understanding how those files and directories relate, it offers little insight.

The [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure) states:

- a project links one or more products to their environment
- a product contains several components
- an environment defines the common layout (etc.) of a project

In addition, there are numerous answers on TeX.SE, but few show a tree with all files and directories:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490603/2148
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377506/2148
- [ConTeXt project structure: Component not linking to environment via product](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/489494/2148)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192552/2148

Comment: Repeating an earlier comment of mine: “projects are essentially collections of environments”

Comment: The beginner's manual should meet most of your requirements. https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/doc/context/sources/general/manuals/start

Comment: Oh, and just to clarify my previous comment: You don't “compile the entire project”.  You always compile the individual products.  I don't think compiling project files is even supported or implemented.

Comment: FWIW, I always use only components and environments. To get  a "collection of environments" I simply contain a main environment which calls other environments.

Comment: “how can setups in the project-wide environments be changed by the product-specific environments?” I'm not sure I understand this question correctly.  Keep in mind that TeX has really weird scoping rules, unlike normal programming languages (for some gotchas regarding ConTeXt environments see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357347 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373283).  Loading order is important.

Comment: You can change values which already happens when you change the interlinespace to `20pt` but there is a difference between a global setting with `\setupinterlinespace[line=20pt]` and local setting `\setupinterlinespace[small]`. The first is for a document wide setup while the second depend on this global value and is used to switch between single or double spacing for certain text blocks. The whole thing has nothing to do with the project structure but the way how `\setupinterlinespace` works.

Comment: You're missing the name after `\startproduct` which results in the wrong output. I suggest to also use the `\input` in you component file and move either the content in this file or make the content itself in a component (components can be nested).

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster, FWIW, the given answer allows the product to override the value for `\setupinterlinespace` set in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works as expected using the given directory hierarchy:

```
% File: prj_para.tex
\startenvironment *
  \setuplayout[
    grid=yes,
  ]

  \define\bookname{Project Name}
\stopenvironment

% File: prd_para.tex
\startenvironment *
  \setuplayout[
    grid=no,
  ]

  \define\bookname{Product Name}
\stopenvironment

% File: component.tex
\startcomponent *
  \project project

  \bookname

  \component contents
\stopcomponent

% File: product.tex (note that * was missing)
\startproduct *
  \project project

  \environment prd_para

  \component component
\stopproduct
```

This produces:

[image: Output, not grid-aligned]

If we remove the `\setuplayout` from `prd_para.tex`, the output changes to grid-aligned typesetting:

[image: Output, grid-aligned]